# Is important for users to show how many shares/likes a post have?

Tags: content, sharing

We all know that shares and likes metrics matter, at least for the developing and marketing teams. but is this important for users?
Would it be better to have a simpler and clearer design for a blog for instance?, a design focused more on content than on sharing? or does showing the number of shares encourage users to actually share a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importance of those numbers is directly related to **Social Proof**. It validates the quality and relevance of the content by showing other people's interest in it.

Quoting Smashing Mag:

> This principle tells us that we like to observe other people’s
>   behaviour to judge what’s normal, and then we copy it.

This article talks about this and other persuasion triggers:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/persuasion-triggers-in-web-design/#trigger3

So in conclusion: yes, it is important for users, as it helps them choose what content is more reliable. Much like how upvotes and downvotes work on many sites, such as stackexchange.

Comment: Nice! that's exactly what i was looking for.